# Compare $~a,b,c~$ with $~1,2,3~$ - Revisited. The virtue of meta-cheating

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a self-answer question that revisits a question that the original poster deleted, themself.

The original question is

> Let $0 \le a \le b \le c$ such that $a+b+c \geq 6,ab+bc+ca=11,abc=6$. 
> Please compare $a,b,c$ with $1,2,3$.

For the record, assuming that the problem composer was accurately excerpted, I regard the problem as very poorly stated.

However, as I discuss in my self-answer, the problem raises underlying issues that I feel warrant Math discussion, on this forum.

Comment: I disagree with "very poorly stated", though that's mainly because I know that the desired answer is $ 1 \leq a \leq 2 \leq b \leq c \leq 3$. With that in mind, how would you suggest rephrasing the problem to be better stated?

Comment: @CalvinLin Let $~S~$ denote the set of all $~(a,b,c)~$ that satisfy the constraints.  Please delineate the set $~S.~$  That is, please describe, as clearly as possible, all values $~(a,b,c)~$ that satisfy the constraints.

Comment: With your phrasing, you're asking for "values that satisfy the constraints" which are the specific solutions sets. For example, $ (1.5, 1.5, 2.5) $ satisfies my (edited) inequality (comparing against 1, 2, 3), but will not be solutions to the problem.  IE The answer to your problem is "Roots of the polynomial $x^3 - Ax^2 + 11x - 6 = 0 $ where $ A \in [6, 6.275...] $ (approximately, I didn't calculate the exact bound)".

Comment: Ooops, sorry, it should be $ 1 \leq a \leq b \leq 2 \leq 3 \leq c $. (I shifted the graph incorrectly. Should have just drawn it out.)

Comment: @CalvinLin This is an interesting point.  Normally, with such a problem, since there is an infinite number of solutions, asking for *all* solutions does not indicate that the problem solver is supposed to list them, but is instead supposed to provide simple rules that will generate any such solution.  However, as you indicated, this might be a misinterpretation of the problem composer's (somewhat concealed) intent.  In such an event, perhaps the composer should specify something like: prove that $a \geq 1, ~b \geq 2, ~c \geq 3.$

Comment: Right, so you're prefer explicitly listing out "Please compare a against 1, b against 2, c against 3" (where the goal is also to determine if $ a \leq 1$ or $a \geq 1$ instead of being given that), as opposed to "Please compare a, b, c with 1, 2, 3" (and it's the combination that's confusing to you).

Comment: @CalvinLin An Algebra-PreCalculus student may well find the syntax *Please compare ...* to be bizarre, as I did.  Posing this syntax to an upper division college Math major would be different.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I fine the phrasing of "please compare x against/to/with y" to be a straightforward inequality comparison. But that might be due to my education upbringing? $\quad$ FWIW I question the original poster's percalculus tag, partly because their other questions indicate a much deeper understanding of math.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum-2 added to complete the problem.

---

$\underline{\text{Soapbox section}}$

If I was a Math student assigned this problem, I would balk.  I would go to the Math professor (or if possible the problem composer) and ask them to explicitly clarify what the exact Math problem is.  However, as a fact of life, Math students are often presented with such poorly worded problems.

Sometimes, as in this case, the student can shoot the gap, and compensate for the poor wording in the Math problem.

---

$\underline{\text{Meta-Cheating}}$

This is a term that I made up, that is somewhat ambiguous.

In my experience, a Math problem posed at the undergraduate level or below, is generally composed to be an application of a specific Math theory.  This suggests that in general, the problem is solvable, if you can determine the pertinent theory.

This suggests that there is sometimes an element of *poker* in attacking such a Math problem, especially if the problem is poorly worded.  You are trying to get inside the head of the Math teacher or problem composer, to discern their intent.

What recently taught theory might well be relevant? 
What is the educational value of the problem? 
If the problem is (somehow) solvable, what would be a likely approach?

Consideration of these (sometimes vague) questions is what I (somewhat ambiguously) refer to as meta-cheating.

---

$\underline{\text{Attack}}$

What specific Math theory *resembles* the constraints:

- $a + b + c \geq ~\text{something}~?$
- $ab + bc + ca = ~\text{something}~?$
- $abc = ~\text{something}~?$

One **guess** is [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).  Personally, I regard this problem as somewhat  unfair, especially when posted (**as is**) on on MathSE.  This is because the problem attacker(s) have no idea what theory previously led to this problem.

However, if this problem is (alternatively) presented in a class/book that recently examined Vieta's formulas, that is different.  Then, it would be natural that the problem composer intended this (poorly worded) problem to be an application of the theory that was just examined.

From Vieta's formulas, you see that $~a,b,c~$ have to be the roots of the 3rd degree equation $~f(x) = x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6 = 0.~$

Since such an equation can only have at most three roots, 
and since $~0 = f(1) = f(2) = f(3),~$ 
the problem solver is supposed to reason that $~\{a,b,c\}~$ must equal $~\{1,2,3\}.$

---

As I indicated, a poorly worded problem that (still) indicates the value of meta-cheating.

---

**Addendum**

Responding to the comment of Calvin Lin:

> The last part isn't quite right, because you're looking at $~a+b+c \geq 6.~$ You dealt with the case of $~a+b+c=6,~$ but not described what happens at larger values. Specifically, the conclusion should be $ ~1 \leq a \leq b \leq 2 < 3 \leq c.$

He's right.  My carelessness in misreading the constraints of the problem.

So, the problem becomes more complicated.

First, suppose that $~a < 1.~$

Then

$$b + c \geq 6 - a > 5.$$

So,

$$ a = \frac{6}{bc} \implies 
\frac{6}{bc}~(b+c) + bc = 11 \implies $$

$$11 > \frac{6}{bc} ~(5) + bc \implies (bc)^2 - 11bc + 30 < 0 \implies $$

$$(bc - 5)(bc - 6) < 0 \implies 5 < bc < 6 \implies abc < 6.$$

This is a contradiction of the premise $~abc = 6.~$

Therefore, you have that $~a \geq 1.$

---

Unfortunately, I was unable to reach similar conclusions for the values of $~b~$ or $~c.$

I considered using Cardano's formula, and trying to plot the rate of change to the roots as a function of the rate of change of $A$.  However, in this situation, Cardano's formula requires (in effect) that you calculate $~\theta~$ as the arccos of a function of $~A,~$ at which point the roots will involve the $~cos(\theta/3)~$.  This results in extremely ugly Math.

So, I gave up looking for a complete analytical solution.

---

**Addendum-2**
Completing the problem.

Highjacking Calvin Lin's analysis, 
let $~g(x) = x^3 - Ax^2 + 11x - 6.$

Then, regardless of whether $~A~$ is restricted so that there will be $~3~$ real roots, for any $~A > 6,~$ you have that

$$g(3) = 54 - 9A < 0, ~g(\infty) > 0.$$

Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, there must always be a root $~c~$ such that $~c > 3,~$ when $~A > 6.$

Further, under the assumption that $~A~$ is restricted, so that there are three real roots $~0 < a \leq b \leq c,~$ it is now established that you must have

- $1 \leq a.$
- $3 \leq c.$

Then, since $~b = \dfrac{6}{ac},~$ this implies that $~b \leq 2.$

Comment: The last part isn't quite right, because the question is for $a+b+c \geq 6$. You dealt with the case of $a+b+c = 6$, but not described what happens at larger values. Specially, the conclusion should be $  1 \leq a \leq 2 \leq b \leq c \leq 3$. $\quad$ In the comment that I made on the deleted post, I referenced using Vieta's formula like you stated, and the idea is to look at the graph of $x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6 = Ax$, from then it should be clear. $\quad$ However, given the tag of pre-calculus, this won't work. OP does have a much deeper understanding of math theory too, so ...

Comment: FWIW Your description of "meta cheating" is simply my process of "problem solving" -> Figuring out what techniques are relevant, based on past experience, or ideas that I'm generating.  $\quad$ It is highly valuable, and shouldn't have a negative connotation (of cheating in the name).

Comment: Note that the last line should be $ 1 \leq a \leq b \leq 2 \leq 3 \leq c $. Sorry for the initial incorrect statement.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long to be a comment. I'm hoping this solution provides you with a bit more insight into the problem, and maybe the relevance to "guessing the topic in order to solve the problem".)

Here is now I solved the problem from the first glance.

By Vieta's formula (which is too advanced for Pre calculus, but i'm guessing that the deleted poster is well aware of), $a, b, c$ are roots to the equation $x^3 - Ax^2 +11x - 6 = 0$, with $ A \geq 6$.

Consider the graphs of

- $y = x^3 - 6x^2 + 11 x - 6 = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$.
- $ y = (A-6)x^2$.

Then, the intersection of these 2 graphs are the desired roots.

By drawing out how the cubic, and understanding how it intersects with the quadratic

[image]

1. It follows that the roots/intersection points satisfy $ 1 \leq a \leq b \leq 2 \leq 3 \leq c$.
2. Furthermore, $A$ cannot be too large. If the slope of the line is too steep, then it would not intersect the cubic in 3 positive reals. (We can determine the max value of $A$ using calculus, or the cubic discriminant.)

---

Second incomplete approach: (Uses a lot more machinery)

Consider the graph of $ g(x)  = x^3 - Ax^2 + 11x - 6$.
By Vieta's formula, the roots of this polynomial correspond to $a, b, c$.

By cubic discriminant, since the roots are all real (and positive), the discriminant $-24 A^3 + 121 A^2 + 1188 A - 6296$ is non-negative, so $ 6 \leq A < 6.212$ (approximately).

Bounding c: Since $g(3) = 54 - 9A \leq 0$, and $ g ( \infty) > 0$ hence by IVT there is a root in $ [ 3 , \infty)$ thus $ c \geq 3$.

Bounding a: Since $ g'(x) = 3x^2 - 2Ax + 11 = \frac{1}{3} ( A - 3x)^2 + \frac{1}{3} ( 33 - A^2)$, on the interval $ ( - \infty, 1]$, this has a minimum at $1$.
Since $g'(1) > 0 $, so for $ r \in (-\infty, 1], g(r) \leq g(1) \leq 0$, thus there are no roots in the interval $(-\infty, 1]$.
Hence, $ 1 \leq a$.

Comment: 1/ Very good point. It's an error, and I've corrected it. The difference of the polynomials should now give $x^3 - Ax^2 + 11x - 6$. $\quad$  2/ Yes, $ b \leq 2$. Remember that my first answer had an error, which I corrected to $ 1\leq a \leq b \leq 2 \leq 3 \leq c$.

Comment: Yes, got it, my blindness.

Comment: I just understood your second proof, that covers $~c \geq 3,~$ specifically.  
This is nice.  One constructive criticism.  I suggest that you edit that specific
portion of your response by removing any discussion of the discriminant.  Later, 
if you need to discuss the discriminant to (for example) attack the last 
missing piece, $~b \leq 2,~$ you can put it back in.

Discussion of the discriminant doesn't add anything to the analysis.  That is,
for all $~A > 6,~$ you have that $~g(3) = 54 - 9A < 0 < g(\infty),~$ so the
IVT must apply.  ...see next comment

Comment: The fact that $~A~$ must be restricted so that there are 
$~3~$ real roots is irrelevant to your argument about $~c \geq 3.$

Comment: That part is more of a scratchpad for my thoughts, than a organized solution. I'm exploring what different ideas might lead to a solution. (FWIW I don't like starting out applying Vieta's formula already. I like your approach of using inequalities to bound.)

Comment: It just hit me.  Between the two of us, we have constructed reasonably elegant proofs that $~a \geq 1,~$ and $~c \geq 3.~$  You also have that $~b = \dfrac{6}{ac},~$ which makes this **game over**.

Comment: Right. Like I said, I wanted an approach that didn't apply Vieta. There could be a way to force $ \max (a, b, c ) > 3$ though some inequality argument.

Comment: Do you like irony?  The whole point of this self-answer question (i.e. meta-cheating rant) is that Vieta's formulas may well facilitate an answer.

Comment: By the way: it is (somewhat) plausible that no such $~\max(a,b,c) > 3~$ argument exists, absent Vieta's formulas, precisely because the IVT proof that $~c \geq 3,~$ is independent of any restriction on $~A > 6.~$  That is, the conclusion that $~c \geq 3,~$ does not require that any other real roots exist.